# SELECT command denied to user

Tags: mysql

Im getting a funny MySQL error.  Here's whats happening:

query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS mycount FROM ip_protection.hits WHERE datetime_created>DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND ip='166.248.6.19'
```

error:

```
SELECT command denied to user 'goatpric_db'@'166.248.6.19' for table 'hits'
```

privileges:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `goatpric\_ip\_protection`.* TO 'goatpric_db'@'%'
```

'hits' is a table in ip_protection.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You grant priveleges to a wrong database name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong database name everywhere. Use correct Database, which according to your question is `ip_protection`.

Comment: ha right you are.  thanks!  Was transferring this from another site.  Totally forgot about the DB names

Answer (score 0):

Add `Use Procedure Bodies = false;` to the connection string.

For example:

```
server=localhost; user id=dbuser; password=password; database=dbname; Use Procedure Bodies=false;
```